# Cant seem to push an object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
class Member {
    constructor(name, type, joindate, dob, points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.joindate = joindate;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.points = points;
    }
    ListInfo() {
        return this.name + "\n" + this.type + "\n" + this.joindate + "\n" + this.dob + "\n" + this.points + "\n";
    }
}

class MemberGroup {
    constrctor() {
        this.List = [];
    }
}

//Member Infos
var Members = new MemberGroup();
Members.List.push(new Member("Leonardo", "Gold", "1 Dec 2019", "1 Jan 1980", 1400));
```

I have checked and this code is definitely syntax valid, no idea where went wrong or what went wrong I  just cant seem to push values into the array.

Comment: `constrctor` <- typo?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```js
class Member {
    constructor(name, type, joindate, dob, points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.joindate = joindate;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.points = points;
    }
    ListInfo() {
        return this.name + "\n" + this.type + "\n" + this.joindate + "\n" + this.dob + "\n" + this.points + "\n";
    }
}

class MemberGroup {
    List = []
}

//Member Infos
var Members = new MemberGroup();
Members.List.push(new Member("Leonardo", "Gold", "1 Dec 2019", "1 Jan 1980", 1400));
console.log(Members.List);
```

You need to **declare** the var otherwise you can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It works, just fix `constrctor` to `constructor` in the MemberGroup class. I changed nothing else.

```js
class Member {
    constructor(name, type, joindate, dob, points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.joindate = joindate;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.points = points;
    }
    ListInfo() {
        return this.name + "\n" + this.type + "\n" + this.joindate + "\n" + this.dob + "\n" + this.points + "\n";
    }
}

class MemberGroup {
    constructor() {  // Fix this typo
        this.List = [];
    }
}

//Member Infos
var Members = new MemberGroup();
Members.List.push(new Member("Leonardo", "Gold", "1 Dec 2019", "1 Jan 1980", 1400));
console.log(Members.List)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, damnn... I used syntax checkers it didn't say anything about a typo, neither did vcdoe, but I assume it was bcuz its recognized as a function due to the error...

Comment: No worries. Select this as the correct answer ;)